# How to run multiple php versions on singile server

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu-14.04

If php 7.0 is running on the server and should i have to run another php version on it none another than php brew . here my server is ubuntu
can anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup different version of PHP as fastcgi backend (with [php-fpm](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php)). Run each as a separated php-fpm service with different port / socket. Then you can specify each site to use a different fastcgi backend in your Apache / Nginx settings.

You can have different PHP version on different site and still have them work in parallelly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible to have two different versions in same server. But you can run one version at a time and can switch between two versions.

Please see this
https://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: can you  please tell the step by step procedure, now iam working in ubuntu